# Trigger log parsing in logstash during start up

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I had troubles with parsing of logs with logstash during startup

Once I add an exta line to log file it is  filtered, output generated to file succesfully
It seems that parsing only is triggerred once change is observer

1) Is there a setting for the input? I've seen http polling, but is there somehting as polling time for a file not http request?

2) I do have number of folders , each folder contains 2 files . Is that possible to parse folder by folder and concatenate fields from these 2 files into a signe json?

```
Folder one1 : obs.out, log.out
Folder two2 : obs.out, log.out
```

Json formed from name field from obs.out and all messages from log.out
So this will be a JSON with "name" :  all the message from log.out

Best Regards

Comment: If you want your file to be read from beginning try [setting the start position](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position) to beginning like so: `input {
    file {
        path => ...
        start_position => "beginning"      
    }
} `